# Does spark recalculate an RDD that has been persisted to disk all over again in a new job?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

Let's say my spark application is composed of **2 jobs**.

Job-1: is composed of a single stage, the result of the stage is persisted

```
rdd1.persist(DISK_ONLY)
```

Job-2: uses the calculated rdd1.  However when I look into [Execution DAG](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html) i see that all the steps that lead up to rdd1 in job-1 is represented as blue boxes.  Although the actual rdd is coloured as green.

Does that mean that the actions that lead up to the rdd are actually skipped?

Answer (score 0):

No
It is actually a shortcoming of the SparkUI. It will only compute steps after rdd1. Though it will show the complete stage in blue.